# Bootstrapping Data from Multiple Sources

Tags: bootstrap, sample-size

Sorry for any wrong use terms since I am not a statistician. I was asked to build a `grand` distribution based on literature identified data (6 in total). However, those six data were reported at various locations with different sample sizes across multiple years. Thus, I do not think it is a good idea of fitting a new distribution by simply pooling those values.

As an alternative, I decide to the non-parametric approach by building a `CDF`. One of the biggest assumption is that `values from each study weight equally`. Then I tried to figure out bootstrapping sample size. For a given I bootstrapping sample size, I sampled from those 6 datasets, and estimate the mean of new dataset. It seems like `10` would be a good size (figure 2).

My questions are:
1. Is my approach OK?
2. data_2 only has 5 obs, will that work?

Thanks in advance!

### Here is the distribution of original data which is very disperse

[image]

### Here is the plot of "Bootstrap Mean VS Sample Size"

[image]

### My code

```
###data#########
data_1<-data.frame(obs=c(3.4E+06, 4.0E+05, 3.8E+06, 2.7E+06, 2.2E+06, 6.5E+05, 3.5E+05, 1.4E+06, 6.0E+05, 1.0E+06, 1.9E+06, 1.4E+06, 1.5E+06, 2.4E+06, 1.3E+06, 1.4E+06, 4.4E+06, 1.3E+06))
data_2<-data.frame(obs=c(2.70E+05, 3.09E+05, 2.71E+05, 3.09E+05, 1.00E+06))
data_3<-data.frame(obs=c(4.42E+03, 6.61E+03, 4.92E+03, 4.92E+03, 8.18E+03, 9.29E+03, 1.12E+04, 8.72E+03, 8.54E+03, 5.60E+03, 6.23E+03, 6.23E+03, 5.37E+03, 5.61E+03, 5.49E+03, 7.08E+03, 5.38E+03, 5.27E+03, 6.79E+03, 6.51E+03, 4.01E+03, 4.96E+03, 4.85E+03, 4.01E+03, 8.24E+03, 2.69E+03, 6.82E+03, 6.82E+03, 5.41E+03))
data_4<-data.frame(obs=c(1.16E+07, 2.51E+07, 1.43E+07, 1.38E+07, 4.71E+07, 6.68E+07, 9.49E+07, 5.05E+07, 5.05E+07, 1.89E+07, 2.51E+07, 2.34E+07, 1.77E+07, 1.77E+07, 1.93E+07, 3.09E+07, 1.77E+07, 1.77E+07, 2.69E+07, 2.69E+07, 8.77E+06, 1.36E+07, 1.33E+07, 8.62E+06, 4.71E+07, 3.78E+06, 2.69E+07, 2.88E+07, 1.65E+07, 2.86E+06, 2.67E+06, 2.86E+06, 2.32E+06, 4.67E+06, 2.67E+06, 8.18E+06, 2.64E+07, 1.01E+07, 5.76E+06, 3.29E+06, 1.08E+07, 8.18E+06, 3.78E+06, 6.18E+06, 8.77E+06, 1.77E+07, 2.18E+07, 6.68E+07, 2.88E+07, 1.89E+07, 2.34E+07, 2.69E+07) )
data_5<-data.frame(obs=c(2.01E+08, 6.87E+07, 1.15E+08, 8.17E+07, 4.31E+07, 6.54E+07, 5.42E+07, 9.04E+07, 1.59E+08, 8.57E+07, 3.16E+08, 9.63E+07, 6.61E+07, 5.48E+07, 9.14E+07, 1.58E+08, 9.70E+07, 2.74E+07, 3.32E+07, 5.97E+07, 1.60E+07, 5.05E+07, 4.60E+07, 5.57E+07))
data_6<-data.frame(obs=c(2.68E+01, 4.31E+01, 2.75E+01, 4.80E+01, 3.30E+01, 1.71E+01, 3.79E+01, 5.31E+01, 1.46E+01, 5.11E+01, 5.32E+01, 5.47E+01, 2.45E+01, 2.37E+01, 3.46E+01, 2.54E+01, 3.25E+01, 3.60E+01, 3.05E+01, 2.28E+01, 2.95E+01, 9.52E+00, 3.47E+01, 1.28E+01, 1.90E+01, 1.86E+01, 2.49E+01, 2.24E+01, 5.60E+01, 4.30E+01, 3.19E+01, 3.53E+01, 4.11E+01, 4.21E+01, 2.92E+01, 2.65E+01, 3.69E+01, 4.20E+01, 1.99E+01, 4.35E+01, 3.89E+01, 4.38E+01, 3.42E+01, 3.37E+01, 2.80E+01, 3.73E+01, 3.84E+01, 3.41E+01, 2.43E+01, 8.69E+00, 2.16E+01, 3.22E+01, 1.30E+01, 8.31E+00, 8.88E+00, 2.02E+01, 1.61E+01, 1.47E+01, 1.28E+01, 1.21E+01, 6.14E+00, 4.76E+00, 3.54E+00, 5.92E+00))
#########################################################


######Bootstrap with different sample sizes 1 to 100#############
set.seed(1) 

boot_avg <- c()
boot_avg_all <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 100, nrow = 1000))


for (k in 1:1000){
    for(sample_size in 1:100) {
        data_1_sample <- sample(data_1$obs, sample_size, replace=T)
  data_2_sample <- sample(data_2$obs, sample_size, replace=T)
        data_3_sample <- sample(data_3$obs, sample_size, replace=T)
  data_4_sample <- sample(data_4$obs, sample_size, replace=T)
        data_5_sample <- sample(data_5$obs, sample_size, replace=T)
  data_6_sample <- sample(data_6$obs, sample_size, replace=T)
        boot_sample <- c(data_1_sample, data_2_sample, data_3_sample, data_4_sample, data_5_sample, data_6_sample)
        boot_avg <- c(boot_avg, mean(boot_sample))
    }
    boot_avg_all[k,] <- boot_avg
    boot_avg <- c()
}

boot_avg_all_mt <- melt(boot_avg_all)

####Bootstrap Mean VS Sample Size#######
ggplot(aes(y = value, x = variable), data = boot_avg_all_mt)+ geom_boxplot()+
      labs(x = "Bootstrap Size", y = "Mean Value")+
      scale_x_discrete(labels = seq(1, 100))
```

Comment: I don't understand your situation. What are the original 6 data? What do you mean that you tried different sizes?

Comment: @gung, sorry for the confusion. Those 6 data are literature reported observations with different sample sizes, locations, etc. I would like to find the minimum bootstrapping sample size...